# Has anyone ever heard of the Rule of Five?

Tags: st.statistics

Def: there is a 93.75% chance that the median of a population is between the smallest and largest values in any random sample of five from the population.

Are there any thoughts?

Comment: Not a research question...

Comment: Based on what? I guess that means you have not heard of it, and have nothing to add. Thanks. 

Comment: @Rich: I actually answered it below, so your abuse is misguided.

Comment: Closed already?  Of course, the 93.75% figure cited is a calculation in elementary probability, not a research question.  But the actual question is whether the name "rule of five" for it is well-known.  I had not heard it.  And Google shows many other uses for the phrase "rule of five" and very few for this use.

Comment: For fun: Assume continuous distribution.  Probability all 5 in the sample are $\gt$ median is $(1/2)^5$, probability all are $\le$ median is $(1/2)^5$, these are mutually exclusive events, so our answer is $1-2\cdot(1/2)^5 = 0.9375$.

Comment: Thanks. The math is clear but the application seems weird. How valuable is this? How difficult is a random sample? 

Comment: This calculation assumes a continuous probability distribution, or at least a distribution with zero density near the median.  For a discrete distribution, you'd need to know the probability that an observation is exactly equal to the population median.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_four

Comment: I'd better simplify my previous statement: This calculation assumes zero probability that an observation is exactly equal to the population median.

Answer (score 2):

Look at http://www.hubbardresearch.com/2009/02/i-am-concerned-about-the-ci-median-and-normal-distribution/

Comment: Why do you answer a question that is, according to your opinion in the comment, not appropriate for the site?

Comment: @unknown: Because I was bored, and it seems like an amusing fact, but this still does not make it appropriate....

Comment: @Igor - my response was not hostile. I merely was stating the appearance of your response, which was that you couldnt/wouldnt contribute. 

Comment: Also, I dont understand the cause to close the discussion or branding this as research oriented or not. Evaluating the appropriate problems or potentials could be research oriented. Ultimately, what does it matter. I am looking at the 'related' questions now and I see a question that asks for the definition of a sample. Are we suggesting that is research? 

Comment: When he says it isn't a research question, he means it isn't a question which is mathematical-research level.  This site is incredibly hostile to "easy" questions, largely because if it wasn't, the hard questions would never get answered.

In general, if you have an easy question (like this, which can be answered with two lines of basic calculation) you're better off asking it in stackoverflow.

Comment: The only problem with that is knowing your question is "easy". :-)  

Comment: The link does not appear to work as intended. Perhaps would be more useful to write up the answer, which is a one-liner.